# Is there a way to parse karma test runner report to find test failures?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, npm, karma-runner, reporting

I tried various libraries like

- karma-verbose-reporter
- karma-failed-reporter
- karma-spec-reporter

and all of them failed to report the number of failures. The best message I've got is this so far

> [corejs_views]:  Chrome Headless 101.0.4950.0 (Mac OS 10.15.7):
> Executed 12 of 16 SUCCESS (0.545 secs / 0.275 secs) TOTAL: 12 SUCCESS

- Are there better reporting available options?
- Is there a way we can parse the above message in CI logs?

My end goal is to identify that all the tests in the suite I'm trying to run passed